# Regular expression (search and replace) with text from MySQL

Tags: php, regex, replace

In PHP I want to remove '\ABC{' and '}' from all places in a text string, e.g.

> This is a short \ABC{text} with some \ABC{codes} that I want to have \ABC{removed}.

is to become

> This is a short text with some codes that I want to have removed.

I've tried the following in PHP;

```
    $string = "This is a short \ABC{text} with some \ABC{codes} that I want to have \ABC{removed}";
    $pattern = '/\\\\ABC{(\w+)}/';
    $replacement = '\1';
    $str = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
    echo $str;
```

and it works well. However, when the $string text is fetched from a MySQL db instead, no replacement is done. What could be wrong? TIA.

Comment: You need to escape the curly braces.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Not in this case. Just run the code, it works fine.

Comment: @mf67: Are you sure you have same string? What do you get when you dump the string from DB?

Comment: Use `var_dump()` to see what's coming from that DB

Comment: @Toto $pattern = '/\\\\ABC\{([\w]+)\}/'; worked well as suggested by Tim.

Comment: What is your PHP version? Here, with 7.0.33 , your code is working fine without escaping curly braces.

Comment: My provider use "PHP Version 7.0.32." I tried without escaping { } and it worked too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [T-Regx](https://t-regx.com):

```
echo Pattern::inject('@(\w+)@', ['\ABC{', '}'])->replace($string)->all()->by()->group(1)->orThrow();
```

You can see demo here: https://repl.it/repls/HorizontalGenerousApplicationpackage